# How can embed meta psql command in sqlalchemy's text module?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

`\set` is a psql meta command.

```
\set var '2024-02-06'
select * from quote where date = :'var';
```

The select command can parse it as :

```
select * from quote where date = '2024-02-06';
```

I want to use it in

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine,text
import pandas as pd
engine = create_engine('postgresql://xx:xx@xx/xx')
sql_str = text('''
                   \set var '2024-02-06'
                   select * from quote where date = :'var';
                ''')
df = pd.read_sql(sql_str,con=engine)
```

It encounter error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 2:                       \set  var  '2024-02-06'
                              ^

[SQL: 
                      \set  var  '2024-02-06'
                      select * from quote where date=:'var'
                      ]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/f405)
```

I knew it can be written as :

```
var = '2024-02-06'
sql_str = text(f"select * from quote where date = {var};")
df = pd.read_sql(sql_str,con=engine)
```

Just want to ask if can embed meta psql command in sqlalchemy's text module?

Comment: 1) `\<command` are `psql` metacommands, they do not work outside [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html). 2) This `sql_str = text(f"select * from quote where date = {var};")` has SQL injection written all over it. Why not use SQLAlchemy [Parameters](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.exec_driver_sql.params.parameters)?